# Efficiently transform multiple columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and I want to transform all columns (say, take the logs or whatever) with columns that match a certain name. So in the example below, I want to take the log of X.1 and X.2, but not Y or Z.1.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  X.1 = sample(1:10),
  X.2 = sample(1:10),
  Z.1 = sample(151:160)
)

# option 1, won't work for dozens of fields
df$X.1 <- log(df$X.1)
df$X.2 <- log(df$X.2)
```

Is there a good, efficient way to do this when the dataframe is several gigabtyes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the case of functions that will return a data.frame:

```
cols <- c("X.1","X.2")
df[cols] <- log(df[cols])
```

Otherwise you will need to use `lapply` or a loop over the columns.  These solutions will be slower than the solution above, so only use them if you must.

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
for(col in cols) {
  df[col] <- c(NA,diff(df[col]))
}
```

Comment: The first method seems great for the calls I need right now, thanks. So obvious, I'm not sure why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 8):

```
vars <- c("X.1", "X.2")

df[vars] <- lapply(df[vars], log)
```

Comment: This worked for me when trying to apply as.integer to a data frame when the accepted solution did not.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
Y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
X.1 = sample(1:10),
X.2 = sample(1:10),
Z.1 = sample(151:160)
)
df
```

assuming that you know those variables which requires conversions in the real dataframe (2 and 3 refers to the 2nd and 3rd variables  in df which are X.1 and X.2)

```
df2=log10(df[c(2:3)])
df2
```

if the variables are far a part in the dataframe you can select them like c(1,3,6,8:10,13) for 1st, 3rd, 6th 8 through  10 and 13th.this works only for numerical variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `dplyr`:

```
cols <- c("X.1","X.2")

df <- df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), log))
```