# Changing multiple columns of a data frame from class 'character' to class 'time' using chron

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have a data frame with multiple columns, some of which I need to change to 'time' class using `chron` so that I can retrieve basic statistics. These columns are currently times stored as characters and formatted like this: hh:mm.

Here is a subset of it as well as the list of columns that need to change:

```
    > Data
     DATE FLT TYPE    REG   AC  DEP  ARR   STD   STA   ATD   ATA
1 15-01-02 953   J  C-GCPT 73M  YVQ  YEV  12:00 12:55 13:00 13:59
2 15-01-04 953   J  C-GCPT 73M  YVQ  YEV  12:00 12:55 13:17 14:13
3 15-01-05 953   J  C-GCPT 73M  YVQ  YEV  12:00 12:55 13:20 14:14

Time_list <-c("STD","STA","ATD","ATA")
```

Here is what I have done to change only one column (and it works):

```
    Data$ATA <- paste0(Data$ATA, ':00')
    Data$ATA<-chron(times.=Data$ATA)

    class(Data$ATA)
    [1] "times"
```

However, I would prefer to be able to do all the columns at the same time since there are many of them. I've tried multiple techniques and some seem to work for the first part, which is pasting ':00', but it always goes wrong for the second part, using `chron` . I seem to have a length problem that I don't understand

1. Using `dmap`

   ```
   Data[,Time_list]<-
     Data%>%
     select(one_of(Time_list)) %>%
     dmap(paste0,':00')

   Data[,Time_list]<-
     Data %>%
     select(one_of(Time_list)) %>%
     dmap(chron,times.=Data[,Time_list])

   **Error in .f(.d[[i]], ...) : 
     .d[[i]] and Data[, Time_list] must have equal lengths**
   ```
2. Using `apply`

   ```
   YEVdata[,(Time_list)] <- lapply(YEVdata[,(Time_list)], paste0,':00')
   Data[,(Time_list)] <- lapply(Data[,(Time_list)], chron, times. =Data[,(Time_list)])
   **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
     X[[i]] and Data[, (Time_list)] must have equal lengths**
   ```
3. Using a `for`loop

I tried using a for loop, but I'm just a beginner and could get anywhere.

4. Using "simple" solution from another Stack Overflow question.

It just made a mess, even pasting.

[Efficiently transform multiple columns of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453440/efficiently-transform-multiple-columns-of-a-data-frame)

Any ideas in plain beginner language would be very appreciated! If it is possible to nest both operations, it would be even better!

Comment: A basic old `lapply` should do it - `data[Time_list] <- lapply(data[Time_list], function(x) times(paste0(data$ATA,":00")) )`

Comment: Essentially the same as the linked question's answer by Josh - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17453493/496803 - the line starting `lapply(...`

Comment: @thelatemail I tried it, and I still get an error: Error in data$ATA : objet de type 'closure' non indiçable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr::mutate_at` would work for this situation.  You define the variables you want to mutate and then define the function you want to use.

You can do the pasting and converting to a time in a single step within `funs` using the `.` notation and nesting functions.

```
library(dplyr)
Data = mutate_at(Data, Time_list, funs(chron(times. = paste0(., ":00"))))
```

Comment: Thanks @aosmith that worked great! Just a follow-up if you don't mind. Some of my time columns are actually written in "h:mm" format OR "hh:mm" (and there are NAs in the columns as well). So I did this: `Data = mutate_at(Data, Delays, funs(chron(times. = paste0("0", .,":00"))))` It seemed to work, even though I had an error message (In unpaste(times, sep = fmt$sep, fnames = fmt$periods, nfields = 3) :
  wrong number of fields in entry(ies) 1, 2) But I can't get my head around how to add an if/else statement. It would be like IF length<4, paste 0 in front, else, only paste ":00". Any ideas?

Comment: @lcabral `chron` appears to work  for me without a leading 0 on the hours.  If you need to add them, `nchar` might help for an `ifelse` statement.